# How do I use Worm Select?

Tags: worms-revolution

I've tried to use Worm Select several times. All that happens is a "switch" symbol of two arrows floats over my worm's head, the item is consumed, and I have control over the same worm. I can even still attack in that same turn, or waste more Worm Selects.

How do I actually use Worm select?

Comment: I'm not going to tell you how to pick your worm. That's just a little too personal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you have activated Worms Select just use the **tab key** to cycle through your worms. If you've remapped or are playing on console it's the same button as switching grenade timers.

Comment: For Worms WMD on Switch, the swap button is R

Comment: PS4, it's Triangle (wtf?!).